# min/max width/height with multiple values

Tags: css

### Edit in 2020 (min, max, clamp functions)

To anyone who get here by search engines:

CSS [min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min) / [max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max) / [clamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp) functions had got some supports in recent (2020) browsers. You may try `max-width: min(200px, 50%);`. You can have a look at these CSS functions while be careful about compatibility issues.

---

### Edit in 2023 (Container Queries)

[Container Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries) had been supported by Chrome 105, Firefox 110, and iOS 16.

---

Original post:

I want limit the width of an `<div>` no more than `50%`, **and** no more than `200px`.

Which means, when `50%` is less than `200px`, it should have the same behavior as `max-width: 50%`, otherwise its behavior becomes `max-width: 200px`.

How can I define this with CSS?
(without [`min` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min), <del>which have not been supported yet</del>)

```
<div class="some_element">Text here</div>
<style>
.some_element {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 200px;
    max-width: 50%; /* this will override previous one, but i want both of them work */
}
</style>
```

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=minmaxwh it has some pretty good support (the min-width your talking about)

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Yes, this feature is old enough and widely supported. But it only accept one value. But I want two.

Answer (score 19):

You can state this desired rule as 50% max width when the page width is less than or equal to 400px, and 200px when the page width is greater than or equal to 400px.  That sounds a lot like a media query!  I handle smaller screen widths first and then override for larger widths, which is this CSS:

```
.some_element {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 50%;
}
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .some_element {
    max-width: 200px;
  }
}
```

If you prefer, you can swap the `50%` and the `200px` and also change the `min-width` to `max-width`.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot set max-width to both 200px and 50%. You could put the element in another element with max-width of 400px:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Text here</div>
</div>


#parent {
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 400px;
}
#child {
    background-color: green;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Why edited? Previous one (with `max-width: 50%`) seems correct but not this one?

Comment: Well I've put it back, width seemed more correct to me ;)

Comment: What about an image? Images don't fit to parent, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="sub">test content</div>
</div>
```

// css

```
#parent {
    max-width: 200px;
}
#sub {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create separate classes and add them dynamically based on outerWidth()

```
.some_element {
        background: red;
        float: left;
        width: auto;
    }

    .widthClass1{
     max-width:50%;
    }

    .widthClass2{
     max-width:200px;
    }


    $(document).ready(function(){
       if($("textDiv").outerWidth()<400){//instead of dividing by 2 I am comparing with 400
         $("textDiv").addClass('widthClass1')
       }else{
         $("textDiv").addClass('widthClass2')
       }
    });
```

Comment: Use javascript will always solve such problems, which is just like `max-width: expression(Math.min(this.parentNode.clientWidth / 2, 200) + 'px');` (codes not tested) in old days. But keeps updating the `classList` or `max-width` of these elements seems too complex. i.e. when window resized, when elements shown/hidden...

Comment: you can keep all these width oriented css in one function and can do on window.onresize too

Answer (score -1):

You can try as mention below

```
.some_element {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    width: 50%; 
    max-width: 200px;        
}
```

Comment: width:auto has no significance here

Comment: This code makes the element have `width: 50%` even if the width of its content is less than `50%`, which is not i wanted.

Comment: @tsh - then you're question is incorrect. Because you state you always want it to be "no more than 50%". You need to clarify what you actually want.

Comment: @carl-johan.blomqvist I want `float: left; width: auto; max-width: min(200px, 50%);`. Which means the width is min(its best fit width, 200px, 50% of its container).

Comment: @tsh - I don't think you do. In a scenario where the container is 300px, min(200px, 50%) => min(200px, 150px) => 150px. This is what happens with above solution? In a 500px scenario: min(200px, 50%) => min(200px, 250px) => 200px. This is also what happens with above solution.

You need to specify what scenarios you are really looking for better I believe.

Comment: @carl-johan.blomqvist `max-width` only apply when its bet-fit width greater than its max-width. for example. `<div style="float: left; max-width: 200px;">x</div>` would be about 10px width not 200px regardless the `max-width` attribute. But since you defined the `width`, it will has a width of 150px if the container is 300px. What I want is ~10px in this case.

Comment: @carl-johan.blomqvist here is an example jsfiddle if it may help: https://jsfiddle.net/28kqvbm4/ Have a look at the first `.inner` element, it will not be rendered as 200px width or 50% of its containers. That is what `max-width` means.

Comment: That's because the container defines what 50% means. So you need to have a container with a width set. If you add width: 100% to .outer, then it works as you expect.