# Specifying multiple max-width values for an element

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have an element which should never be larger than let's say 90% of the container's width *and* never exceed an absolute width of 800px.

Using CSS I can specify either

```
#element {
    max-width: 90%;
}
```

or

```
#element {
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a syntax like

```
#element {
    max-width: 90% 800px;
}
```

or

```
#element {
    max-width: max(90%, 800px);
}
```

which does the trick.

Is there a way to solve this using CSS only? I would like to avoid JavaScript here.

I already found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568424/min-max-width-height-with-multiple-values), which unfortunately, does not work for me.

Comment: Use CSS Media Queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use:

```
#element {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

This way `#element`'s `width` will always be exactly `90%` of the parent's if that's lower than `800px` or `800px` otherwise.

Alternatively, depending on what you are trying to do, you should use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) or a wrapping element.